# Unable to find cause of an update statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am able to retrieve the record from GET request, but fail to update the record using PATCH request. Any suggestion on how debug this issue?

```
def show
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    render json: { status: :ok, message: 'Find the product ', data: @product }
end

def update
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])

        if @product.update(product_params)
                render json: { status: :ok, message: 'Product updated!!! ', data: @product }
        else
            render json: { status: :error, message: 'Product not available!!!', data: @product }
    end
end

private

def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:title, :price, :count)
end
```

Curl requests:

```
curl -i -X GET 'localhost:3000/products/1'  
      {"status":"ok","message":"Find the product ","data":{"id":1,"title":"cell phone","price":"999","count":"99","created_at":"2019-01-19T16:12:09.717Z","updated_at":"2019-01-21T09:01:56.056Z"}}
curl -i -X PATCH 'localhost:3000/products/1' -d '{"product":{ "title": "t", "price": "1.23", "count": "3"}}'
     {"status":"error","message":"Product not available!!!","data":{"id":1,"title":"t","price":"1.23","count":"3","created_at":"2019-01-19T16:12:09.717Z","updated_at":"2019-01-21T09:01:56.056Z"}}


              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
        welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                                                                 welcome#index
     product_purchase GET    /products/:product_id/purchase(.:format)                                                 products#purchase
             products GET    /products(.:format)                                                                      products#index
                      POST   /products(.:format)                                                                      products#create
          new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)                                                                  products#new
         edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             products#edit
              product GET    /products/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#show
                      PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#update
                      PUT    /products/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#update
                      DELETE /products/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#destroy
                 root GET    /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `product` in the GET and `products` in the PATCH request. Check your routes file if you have defined the correct route.

Also based on your curl responses, it seems the product was updated. But the status and the message is from the else block. Try using `update!` to check for any errors

Comment: Use update! showing the reason is because of the validation. Now it works fine . Thanks for your help!